# `geom_abline` and `facet_wrap` seem incompatible

Tags: r, ggplot2

I get errors when I use `geom_abline` in the same plot as `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`, and I don't understand why. For example

```
# Example data
ex <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10, f=gl(2, 5))

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=ex, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=0) + 
  facet_wrap(~f)
```

causes `Error in if (empty(data)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`.

Above I set the data in the `geom_point` layer because later on I will add data from a different data frame. This has something to do with the problem, because when I set the data in the base layer I get a different error:

```
ggplot(ex, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=0) +
  facet_wrap(~f)
```

`Error in as.environment(where) : 'where' is missing`

#### Workaround

There's an easy workaround: If I make a data frame to define a 1:1 line and plot it using `geom_line` I get essentially the same plot I would have gotten from `geom_abline`...

```
# Define a 1:1 line with data
one_to_one <- data.frame(xO=range(ex$totalcells), yO=range(ex$totalcells))

# Plot the 1:1 line with geom_line
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=ex, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_line(data=one_to_one, aes(x=xO, y=yO), colour="black") +
  facet_wrap(~f)
```

[image]

...**so this question is more about *why* those errors arise** (and whether they represent a bug or expected behavior) rather than how to work around the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
ggplot(ex, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_abline(slope=1, intercept=0) +
  facet_wrap(~f)
```

Note the additional `geom_point()` I added, based on your second example.

Comment: So apparently `geom_abline` requires pre-existing mappings in the base layer for some reason?

Comment: In your first example, I think the `aes` and `data` are local to `geom_point()`, and therefore `geom_abline` has nothing to work with. The code that works above simply moves them from `geom_point()` to the global `ggplot()`, making them available to `geom_abline()`.

Comment: I think the point is that at least one layer needs to map something to the data, and my (wild) guess is that since abline doesn't need x and y they're not inherited from the global mapping: `ggplot(ex) + geom_abline(aes(x,y), slope=1, intercept=0) + facet_wrap(~f)` seems to work.